# Magento2 developer mode doesnt generate static files on demand

Tags: magento2, static-content, static-content-deploy

I am running Magento 2 locally in developer mode

After installing i would not  expect to have to run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` if in developer mode.

However,  the only directory under static is **_requirejs** and all css and other assets generate a 404 on the frontend.

Is the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command required even in developer mode or do i have an issue with this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are in Apache:

1. Check you have the correct .htaccess file under pub/static folder https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/pub/static/.htaccess. Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/pub/static/.htaccess#L21 which redirects requests to static.php
2. Make sure your mod rewrite module is working properly.
3. Make sure apache is reading .htaccess files.

`Apache 2.2
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all`

`Apache 2.4
AllowOverride All
Require all granted`

If you are in Nginx:

Update configurations using https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/nginx.conf.sample.
Check https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/nginx.conf.sample#L111 which redirects requests to static.php

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you are running Apache: make sure that `mod_rewrite` module is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Magento on Windows perhaps [try this solution (German)](https://www.econcess.de/blog/onlineshop-erstellung-magento/325-magento-2-onlineshop-statische-dateien-im-developer-mode), we had to change the file \vendor\magento\framework\App\StaticResource.php due to dirctory separator issues.